# Flutter list items change position with animation

Tags: android, flutter, android-recyclerview, flutter-animation

The following code has a list from 1 to 100, on top has three buttons to change the order of the list (increasing, decreasing or shuffle).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class SamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
  SamplePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SamplePageState createState() => _SamplePageState();
}

class _SamplePageState extends State<SamplePage> {
  _SamplePageState();

  final _list = new List<int>.generate(100, (i) => i + 1);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
              _list.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
            }),
            child: Text(
              "Sort increasing",
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
              _list.sort((a, b) => b.compareTo(a));
            }),
            child: Text(
              "Sort decreasing",
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
              _list.shuffle();
            }),
            child: Text(
              "Shuffle",
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
                '${_list[index]}',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Everything works but as I'm new to flutter, I'm wondering if it is possible to make the items of the list change with animation.

On android world, we can do it through the [setHasStableIds](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#setHasStableIds(kotlin.Boolean)) in a RecyclerView adapter, I imagine the approach on flutter maybe be different, but I guess it is possible to achieve the same result, I would like to know how.

---

## Edited

I'm adding here a gif of how items change position animated when you are using a native recyclerview, this animated change of positions is what I'm looking for.

[image: animation sample]

Comment: I'm looking for the Row version of this. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet @BurakMeteErdoğan let us know if you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it out myself but maybe AnimatedListView will do the trick.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html

But as I said me myself I haven't tested it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: **ReorderableListView** and his property *onReorder*

```
ReorderableListView(
            children: list
                .map((m) => ListTile(
                key: ObjectKey(m),
                title: Text(m),
            )).toList(),
            onReorder: _onReorder,
        )
```

Source link: https://www.programmersought.com/article/4678939801/

Comment: The idea is not reorder the list but "shuffle" items animated. I'm adding a gif to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: So you need to use Animated List.